# FreeBSD 13.1 under Hyper-V on Windows 10 Pro

Tags: freebsd, mouse

I am building a new FreeBSD 13.1 Workstation on a Windows 10 machine under Hyper-V.  I have been successful doing this with previous version of FreeBSD, back to releases 6, and previous releases of Windows back to XP Pro.
I have a couple problems with recognizing my mouse.  I am using a Logitech M217 wireless mouse, which I expect to be seen as a Hyper-V mouse.
I expect the mouse to work in any Xorg window manager.   The mouse does work in Xorg under 12.3.  Also the mouse isn’t working on the console, outside of Xorg.    It should be able to select/cut/past because ‘allscreens_flags=”-m on”’ is in /etc/rc.conf.  It should work with text-based terminals and in xterm.  It doesn’t work with release 13.1 or release 12.3.
In /var/log/console.log, I’m troubled with the following lines;
•   FreeBSD13 kernel: [: mouse: unexpected operator
•   FreeBSD13 kernel: Starting default mousedmoused: unable to open /dev/psm0: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

It seem a know problem, for the device not found, that the FreeBSD team will **not** work on it.

[Bug 221074 - Hyper V Gen 2 install has no mouse](https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=221074)

Some comment from the dev;

> As I said, no plan for it yet.  The Hyper-V console is *not* suitable
> for X related stuffs.  And again, if you want to use X, use VNC; it is
> recommended and works quite well on both gen1 and gen2 Hyper-V.

or, which offer a workaround;

> Well, if you *do* want to stick w/ using the X on the Hyper-V console,
> then use gen1 VM, which has an emulated PS2 mouse.  I actually don't
> see gen2 VM buys anything useful for desktop users.